How to determine velocity components from the GPS module?
I am building a mobile robot for transfer purposes. Using the GPS and IMU (accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer), I would like to track its absolute position and orientation. I am stuck on the position part.
I got a good orientation matrix from the IMU using Madgwick's filter to extract the quaternion rotation matrix which I multiplied with the rotation matrix around the z axis to compensate for magnetic declination in my country. I calibrated the IMU's magnetometer and even accelerometer using Matlab's functions described here and here. I managed to even find very good values for beta and zeta gains experimentally. This allowed me to rotate the measured acceleration vector from the IMU's frame to the Earth's frame. Note that I am using the North-East-Down coordinate system.
The next step is to form a Kalman filter which would predict the velocity and position from the accelerometer vector I obtained and correct those values using GPS values.
This is my first time working with a GPS module. I obtained the latitude, longitude and altitude from the GPS which I can use to correct the position obtained from the accelerometer by double integration. However, I don't understand how to obtain the velocity components from the GPS module to correct the velocity components I obtained from the accelerometer single integration.
I noticed I can only get from my GPS module (NEO 6M) speed over ground which is essentially the absolute speed (calculated as $v_{abs}=\sqrt{v_x^2 +v_y^2 + v_z^2}$), not any of the components by itself. Now I know I can get velocity components also by doing distance over time calculation (which can increase the error of the measurement). However, I am not sure if this is the right approach. So my questions are:

How to best obtain the velocity components from the GPS?
Can I somehow use the speed-over-ground information I have to improve GPS velocity calculations? If yes, how?


uBlox 6 series should be outputting velocity information in NAV-VELECEF and NAV-VELNED message packets. Did you check if you are able to receive velocity information in these packets.
Are you encoding NAV-POSLLH or NAV-POSECEF packets to obtain the position? If you do, you can do a similar thing with NAV-VELNED / NAV-VELECEF packet to obtain the velocity information. You can use the Receiver Description document to correctly encode the information from the packets.

Jackpot. VELNED gives me what I need. Thank you :D
